# modifying QTP imported Environment variables

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables, qtp

Using QTP, I need to import environmental variables from an XML sheet, but there that is the imported ones are the imported Environmental variables are on read only mode, it cannot be edited.

I need to know if there is any way to import environment variables and edit them and i need to know, somehow, is there any method to create environment variables from code(programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create environment variables from code, use below loc:

```
Environment("variablename")="Variablevalue" ' Create and intialise environment variable

Print Environment("variablename") 'To retrieve value of variable
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much Programr, AutomatedChaos :)
This were extremely helpful